# If Variable++ as count++ is null for next page how to return in java/android so that app dont crash

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I have to change my url dynamically for android app to do pagination using Wordpress Rest API, it is working and loading fine in my app but after loading the last page when count++ is null, just scrolling more after the last page app crash so how to return a null value so that the app don't crash.

```
count = 0;
public void getRetrofit(){

        int numberPage = count++;

        String url = "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page="+numberPage;
```

Please anyone help me to fix this issue for the following Java Code. .I shall be very thankful if someone help me as i am getting frustrated from many days. Below is my following java code. I know i have to insert something like if(count++ == null){return;} but i am able to figure it out how to do that.Thanking you again.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private ArrayList<Model> list;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    Boolean isScrolling = false;
    int currentItems, totalItems, scrollOutItems;
    int count = 1;

    private String baseURL = "https://example.com";

    public static List<WPPost> mListPost;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        list = new ArrayList<Model>();

        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter( list, MainActivity.this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if(newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL)
                {
                    isScrolling = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                currentItems = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItems = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                scrollOutItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if(isScrolling && (currentItems + scrollOutItems == totalItems))
                {
                    isScrolling = false;
                    getRetrofit();

                }
            }


        });
        getRetrofit();

    }
    public void getRetrofit(){

        int numberPage = count++;

        String url = "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page="+numberPage;

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RetrofitArrayApi service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayApi.class);
        Call<List<WPPost>>  call = service.getPostInfo(url);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<WPPost>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Response<List<WPPost>> response) {
                Log.e("mainactivyt", " response "+ response.body());
                mListPost = response.body();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                for (int i=0; i<response.body().size();i++){
                   list.addAll(list.getItems());
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
    public static List<WPPost> getList(){
        return  mListPost;
    }

}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
10-14 21:23:33.358 17119-17124/com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=125KB, data=101KB
10-14 21:23:33.360 17119-17124/com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=118KB, data=78KB
10-14 21:23:33.901 17119-17124/com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=122KB, data=91KB
10-14 21:23:33.902 17119-17124/com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=122KB, data=91KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
10-14 21:23:36.324 17119-17119/com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod E/mainactivyt:  response [com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod.WPPost@2863a0d]
10-14 21:23:36.324 17119-17119/com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod E/main:  title 21 This is the Wp Sample Post 13
10-14 21:23:36.410 17119-17119/com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod E/mainactivyt:  response [com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod.WPPost@a696a09, com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod.WPPost@927140e, com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod.WPPost@e93fe2f, com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod.WPPost@3cfbc3c, com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod.WPPost@d359dc5, com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod.WPPost@144631a, com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod.WPPost@6c4e4b, com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod.WPPost@6fa6028, com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod.WPPost@8d75141, com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod.WPPost@7b596e6]
10-14 21:23:36.410 17119-17119/com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod E/main:  title 11 This is the Wp Sample Post 31
     title 12 This is the Wp Sample Post 30
     title 13 This is the Wp Sample Post 29
10-14 21:23:36.411 17119-17119/com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod E/main:  title 14 This is the Wp Sample Post 28
     title 15 This is the Wp Sample Post 21
     title 16 This is the Wp Sample Post 20
     title 17 This is the Wp Sample Post 19
10-14 21:23:36.412 17119-17119/com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod E/main:  title 18 This is the Wp Sample Post 18
     title 19 This is the Wp Sample Post 17
10-14 21:23:36.413 17119-17119/com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod E/main:  title 20 This is the Wp Sample Post 16
10-14 21:23:39.474 17119-17124/com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=252KB, data=208KB
10-14 21:23:39.478 17119-17124/com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=220KB, data=156KB
10-14 21:23:41.213 17119-17119/com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod E/mainactivyt:  response null
10-14 21:23:41.213 17119-17119/com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
10-14 21:23:41.214 17119-17119/com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod, PID: 17119
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at com.namansoftlabs.wordpressmymod.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:193)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:822)
```

Comment: numberPage is an 'int'. these cannot be null. If you are seeing a NullPointerException, it is NOT because numerPage is null (url cannot be null either in your code snippet). Something else is and you haven't pasted the relevant parts to be able to tell.

Comment: you sure count hold null? because if count is nullable it should generate compile time error

Comment: Can you post the code where you call `getRetrofit()` and where you want to test the nullity of `count`? with the code above, count can not be null

Comment: I have added the Complete Code and i am not able to fix it, please Sir help me out, i am totally frustrated.

Comment: @KatrinaPathak better post the stack trace of the exception too

Comment: make sure response.body() is not null .
Please post the full stack trace.

Visit http://helpmepal.org if you want someone to connect to teamviewer & try to solve your problem

Comment: Sir i have posted the Stack trace also , please have a look Sir @ Ayush Gupta , @ Prakash, @ gratien asimbahwe, @ rzwitserloot, @ Sumit raj

Comment: What is line 193 of MainActivity?

Comment: @ Code-Apprentice, Sir the line 193 of MainActivity is                 for (int i=0; i<response.body().size();i++){}

Comment: Well it tells you that the NPE occurs at line 193 inside the method `onResponse` after calling `size()`. Now look at your code. The line must be `for (int i=0; i<response.body().size();i++){` which indicates that `response.body()` returns `null`

Comment: @QBrute yes Sir it is , but sir i think the line 193 is okay even though it gives the null value because for 1 page and second page while scrolling in my app everything is okay but when it reaches 3rd page it crash, so i think i have to change some thing else to call pagination using wordpress rest api. Any solution sir, please help me i shall be very thankful.

Comment: No, that's exactly the reason for your exception. If `response.body()` is `null` and then you call `size()` on it, you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Sir, please help how to do that  as i am not from a computer back ground and what ever i have learned its all from my self study using internet, it is something like a challenge for me learning myself. Sir i dont know what to do and how to figure it out. Please help me @QBrute

Answer (score 1):

Your code crashes here

```
for (int i=0; i<response.body().size();i++)
```

because

```
response.body()
```

is null